# Reading input from command line

Tags: php

I have had this function for a very long time and it has served me well up until now. Very simple script, I run it in command line (windows, I believe command prompt is the proper term) and I get weird results, see

```
function readline($prompt = '') {
    echo $prompt;
    return rtrim(fgets(STDIN), "\n");
}

$name = readline('Enter Name: ');
exit($name . 'dgd');
```

[image]

Instead of the expected `bratdgd`. Anyone can tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, the newlines are represented by the `"\r\n"` character sequence, not just `"\n"`.  You need to trim that as well.

[`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) will trim all whitespace if you simply omit the second parameter:

```
function readline($prompt = '') {
    echo $prompt;
    return rtrim(fgets(STDIN));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows line endings are CRLF - `\r\n`.

You have removed the `\n`, leaving only `\r`, which by itself moves the cursor to the start of the *current* line and overwrites what's there.

Hence...

```
brat   \r here
dgd    overwrites the above line
dgdt   result
```